# How does the unary minus operator work on booleans in C++?

Tags: c++, unary-operator

I am currently converting some OpenCV code from C++ to Java. I can't use JavaCV, as we need the conversion in native Java, not a JNA. At one point in the code, I get the following assignment:

```
dst[x] = (uchar)(-(kHit >= kForeground));
```

Where `dst` is `uchar*`, `kHit` and `kForeground` are `int`s.

I've been unable to find anything about how this works, and Java will not recognize it as an operation. There is an operation on these two variables at another point in the code, and it stores one of two values: 255 or 0.

The code in question comes from `opencv/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix.cpp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ a boolean expression produces one of two values - `0` or `1`. When you apply the unary minus `-` to the result, you get `0` or `-1`. When you re-interpret `-1` as `uchar`, you get `255`.

You can convert this expression to Java with a conditional:

```
dst[x] = (kHit >= kForeground) ? 255 : 0;
```

Because of branching, it is not going to be as fast as the original one. There's little you can do about the speed of it, however, as Java lacks abilities to re-interpret boolean values as numerics.

Comment: This makes sense, and is something I could have very easily tested and discovered on my own. Thanks for pointing it out so concisely.

Comment: Technically the boolean expression yields either `true` or `false`, that when promoted to an `int` will get the values `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 6):

`kHit >= kForeground` returns either `true` or `false`, which in C++ sort of means `1` or `0`. The minus in front transforms this to `-1` or `0`. The cast to `uchar` (`(uchar)`) returns `0` for `0` and wraps to `255` for the negative `-1`.

<del>Following Konrad's comment, I'm also skeptical this is well defined.</del> It is well defined, but it's still an awful piece of code in terms of readability. :)

Comment: On *some* compiler/machine. This code is needlessly unportable.

Comment: Doesn't the C++ standard explicitly specify unsigned types to behave as if twos-complement, so this should be well defined (as true==1 and false==0 is well defined, too)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The standard specifies that `A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.` [conv.prom], and that `If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)` [conv.integral]. So I think this code is actually well-defined and portable across compliant compilers.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `bool` is neither signed nor unsigned, but it does not even matter since it will be promoted to `int` *before* the unary - is applied. Regarding the last paragraph in the answer, it is well defined. The standard guarantees that. Besides the quote from Luc, the standard dictates that integral promotion is applied for the evaluation of unary -.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's what I meant. The conversion from `bool` to `int` is well defined, as well as the conversion from negative to unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

What it basically does is following:

```
kHit >= kForeground
```

is an expression of type bool

```
-(kHit >= kForeground)
```

converts this bool into an int (based on `true==1` and `false==0`) and negates it, which results in `true==-1` and `false==0`.

This is then converted into a `uchar`, which results in `-1==255` and `0==0`.

It has to be noted that though seeming as using the underlying implementation details of the numbers, all those conversions are guaranteed by the C++ and C standards, as negative unsigned numbers are specified to behave according to twos-complement.

But if Java doesn't support this, you can always replace it by a conditional assignment:

```
dst[x] = (kHit>=kForeground) ? 255 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(kHit >= kForeground)` yields a boolean that has value `true` or `false`. When the unary `-` is applied, the `bool` gets promoted to an `int`, and the conversion yields `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`. After the promotion, the sign is changed into `-1` or `0` and then it is converted to `uchar` by the outer cast.

Note that the important bit of information is that the unary `operator-` is not applied to a boolean, but the boolean is converted to `int` and it is then applied. That can be tested with a bit of template magic:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct same_type {
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct same_type<T,T> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
template <typename T>
void f( T value ) {
    std::cout << "Is int? " << std::boolalpha << same_type<T, int>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Is bool? " << same_type<T, bool>::value << "\n";
}
int main() {
    f(-true);
}
```

The `f` template tests the type of the passed argument against `int` and `bool` by using the `same_type` templates above (trivial enough to understand). If we call the `f` template with `-true` as argument type deduction will set `T` to be the type of the expression `-true`. If you run the program, you will see that it prints `Is int? true\nIs bool? false`.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you could make the illustration of integral conversion much clearer with two basic overloads. `void f(int) { cout << "int\n"; } void f(bool) { cout << "bool\n"; } f(true); f(-true);`

Comment: @LucTouraille: I guess, I just had that [hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) in my toolbox (now that I think of it there is a simpler approach: `template <typename T> void print_type(T); print_type(-true);` (`print_type` declared, not defined) will tell you the type in the linker message