# Translate C++ function to Java

Tags: java, c++, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

First of all sorry if the question is basic, but I am not a C++ expert.

I am investigating Genetic Algorithms in Java and I arrived to this link, which contains interesting info: http://web.archive.org/web/20100216182958/http://fog.neopages.org/helloworldgeneticalgorithms.php

However, I quite can´t understand what is this method doing:

```
int fitness(bool* chromosome)
{
    // the ingredients are:  0     1     2     3   4    5     6
    //          salt sugar lemon egg water onion apple
    return ( -chromosome[0] + chromosome[1] + chromosome[2] 
         -chromosome[3] + chromosome[4] - chromosome[5] 
         -chromosome[6] );  
}
```

With academic purposes, I am trying to "translate" the C++ program to Java, but I don´t understand this method, what is exactly returning? (I assume it´s operating with an array.)

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least leave some constructive feedback via a comment. At least OP didn't just post the code and say "translate to Java please".

Comment: @JonnyHenly THANKS. I wish everyone in StackOverFlow be like you. I read how to write a good question and I don´t know why are they downvoting...

Comment: the code in the link is C not C++

Comment: @tobi303 It´s C++. If you take the time to compile the program in the link I gave with a C compiler, you will see it won´t work.

Comment: you may be right but the page claims its C and I dont see any C++ in there

Comment: seems like it does not compile because the author forgot to `#include<stdbool.h>`. Otherwise it is pure C

Comment: anyhow imho once you compile it with a c++ compiler it is c++, nevermind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning an integer.  Booleans are being converted to integers before being added/subtracted together.  True is 1.  False is 0.

Here's the Java translation.  In our case, we're having to convert the booleans to integers ourselves.

```
int fitness(boolean[] chromosome)
{
    int[] intChromosome = toInt(chromosome);

    // the ingredients are:  0     1     2     3   4    5     6
    //          salt sugar lemon egg water onion apple
    return ( -intChromosome [0] + intChromosome [1] + intChromosome [2] 
         -intChromosome [3] + intChromosome [4] - intChromosome [5] 
         -intChromosome [6] );  
}

int[] toInt(boolean[] values) {
    int[] integers = new int[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        integers[i] = values[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return integers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, but it´s not working, it says operator - can´t be applied to boolean

Comment: Ah!  That's a good point.  Let me figure out what C++ is doing with this weird boolean math, and I'll correct this.

Comment: @BenM. This SO question might provide some insight - [How does the unary minus operator work on bolleans in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544041/how-does-the-unary-minus-operator-work-on-booleans-in-c)

Comment: No problem Ben, I suspect it´s a c++ - Java incompatibility

Comment: @stackman In C/++ a boolean expression produces either `0` or `1`, if you put a unary minus in front, it becomes `-0 (0)` or `-1`. Java can do it as well, just not so straight forward.

Comment: I added a method to convert the boolean array into an integer one, based on C/C++ rules.  If anyone knows a cleaner way, that'd be great!

Comment: Instead of creating a new array, how about just inlining it: `-(chromosome[0]?1:0) + (chromosome[1]?1:0) + ...` and make it more readable by aligning them on 7 lines.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Andreas for the comments. @Ben M., is there a missing "return integers;" in the "toInt" method?

Comment: @BenM. no worries at all my friend. Thanks to your code, my whole program it´s working. I´ll take on account this conversion in the future, I learned a lot from it. Thanks in advance buddy!